# Why does my last data on csv get delete by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm new to python and I'm working on a little writing in CSV project
but every time that I run it it will delete my last data and write a new one 
this is the code

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='')as f:
    User_new_pass = input('enter your new password: ').strip()
    User_new_id = ' ' + input('enter your new user name: ').strip()
    User_new_info = [User_new_pass, User_new_id]
    linewriter = csv.writer(f)
    linewriter.writerow(User_new_info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append to the file, you should change the mode in the `open()` function:

```
with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='')as f:
    # your code
```

`a` - `Open file in append mode. If file does not exist, it creates a new file.`

`w` - `This Mode Opens file for writing. If file does not exist, it creates a new file. If file exists it truncates the file.`